# Google Drive Sharing Subfolders Permissions Inheritance Issue

Tags: google-drive-api, sharing, drive

[image: How a Sender Sends a Folder Structure]
Sender: Assuming all the three levels in this folder structure are shared with a user
[image: How it appears]
How it appears to the Receiver in the "Shared with Me' Folder
[image]
How it shows up in My drive of the receiver account, the hierarchy gets Messed up big time.

This is handled smoothly by other Providers. Is this a Google Bug or a feature. How Do I handle it for Large organisation level folder structure where the number of users exceed a couple of thousands

Comment: Have you tried just setting `FOlder 1` and share it to others? I believe hierarchical folders and files will be shared along with it.